# Adding playlist.me to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get this [playlist.me](http://playlist.me/w/i.php) code embedded into my WordPress site. They suggest to put it under the `<body>` tag but that doesn't work for WordPress within `header.php`. I've searched all over and no one has posted up about this which is mind boggling.

```
<!-- Song Player http://playlist.me -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://playlist.me/w/script.js" data-config="{'skin':'skins/pink/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':false,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'top','showplaylist':false,'playlist':'https://soundcloud.com/freshfuzion/sets/fresh-fuzion-collective'}" >
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://playlist.me/skins/">SCM player skins</a>
</noscript>
<!-- playlist.me script end -->
```

Comment: Which WordPress theme are you working on?

Comment: I'm using a premium theme called Outspoken http://outspoken.wpshower.com/

Comment: If you look in the themes folder (probably `wp-content/themes/outspoken`, and search for `<body` across files, you should get as result the file (if it's not `header.php` that includes the opening `body` tag after that your player script goes.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, it would be great if you accept my answer when it helped you. It's a measurement to keep search results in Stack Overflow clean. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the themes folder (probably `wp-content/themes/outspoken`, and search for `<body` across files, you should get the file as result (if it's not `header.php` that includes the opening `body` tag after that your player script goes).